# Scheduled startup on Win10 Dell Inspiron?

Tags: windows-10, scheduled-task, startup

I want my Dell Inspiron 15 3567 laptop to automatically switch on every morning at a particular time. I have been trying to work it out, opened my laptop's BIOS settings, but couldn't find anything related to scheduled startups till now. I am aware of the Windows Task Scheduler though and have been using that extensively for the past year now, for various tasks, including also laptop restart and switch-off. My understanding is that any scheduling except for the startup can be set up in the Task Scheduler; for scheduled startup I need the BIOS tinkering though. Could someone please point me in the right direction as to where I can set that exactly, or let me know if it is even possible for this model?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the "start this machine to run this task" in task scheduler? Try upgrade your bios to hopefully get the settings back. Other than that - don't buy dell. One final workaround could be to use wake on LAN from a different device